# Selecting nodes possessing all/any values in list

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm looking to take a delimited list of category IDs provided in one element...

```
<Categories>851|849</Categories>
<MatchType>any</MatchType>
```

...and use them to style other elements...

```
<Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 1</Page>
<Page CategoryIds="849|850|">Page 2</Page>
<Page CategoryIds="848|850|">Page 3</Page>
<Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 4</Page>
<Page CategoryIds="848|850|851">Page 5</Page>
<Page CategoryIds="848|849|850">Page 6</Page>
```

...based on whether or not they possess **any** (or **all**... depending on what's indicated in `<MatchType>`) of the given IDs.

Also, the IDs aren't necessarily going to be given in the order that they appear in the CategoryIds attribute, and the string inside the attribute isn't expected to contain the exact `<Categories>` string.

Is something like this possible using XSLT/XPath 1.0? I know that 2.0 has a tokenizing function that would be perfect for this, but unfortunately the CMS I am working with does not yet support 2.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: | &#124; http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96

Comment: Tokenization has been done in XSLT 1.0 for many years and I'd like to answer your question. The only problem is that I completely *don't* understand what you want to achieve -- please, edit your question and provide: 1. The source XML document (as short as possible). 2. The wanted result. 3. Explain how particular parts of the output must be calculated from which parts of the input.

Comment: OK now you have two solutions -- Alejandro's and mine -- both working and both good. I finally understood what you wanted (be warned for your future questions that the way you express the problem is difficult to understand) and produced a solution that I find good according to my (high) standards. It is up to you now to ask questions in case something in the solutions is not clear and to accept one of them. And simply to say "thank you for your effort".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not clear at all from this question what you want to do, here is an answer to a part of it:

> Is something like this possible using
>   XSLT/XPath 1.0? I know that 2.0 has a
>   tokenizing function that would be
>   perfect for this, but unfortunately
>   the CMS I am working with does not yet
>   support 2.0.

Tokenization has been done in XSLT 1.0 for many years. While it is possible to write your own recursive teplate for tokenizing a string, it is good to remember that such a solution already is available in the FXSL library and it is guaranteed to work, is more powerful than the typical tokenization implemented and has no known bugs -- just ready to use.

**This is the `str-split-to-words` template and here is one typical example of using it**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">

   <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" 
                          select="', &#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="word">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ' ', ., '&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>Sorry, kid, first-borns really are smarter.
First-borns are typically smarter, while
younger siblings get better grades and
are more outgoing, the researchers say</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
1 Sorry
2 kid
3 first-borns
4 really
5 are
6 smarter.
7 First-borns
8 are
9 typically
10 smarter
11 while
12 younger
13 siblings
14 get
15 better
16 grades
17 and
18 are
19 more
20 outgoing
21 the
22 researchers
23 say
```

**Do note** that the template accepts a parameter named `pDelimiters` in which multiple delimiters can be specified.

**Update**: I finally understood what the OP wants with this problem. Here is my solution, which again uses the `str-split-to-words` template for tokenization:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
>

   <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>

   <!-- to be applied upon: test-strSplit-to-Words2.xml -->

   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vCategories">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select=
          "/*/select-criteria/Categories"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" 
                          select="'|'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/pages/Page">
        <xsl:with-param name="pCategories" select=
         "ext:node-set($vCategories)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pMatchType" select=
        "*/select-criteria/MatchType"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Page">
     <xsl:param name="pCategories"/>
     <xsl:param name="pMatchType" select="any"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vDecoratedCurrent"
          select="concat('|', @CategoryIds, '|')"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vSelected" select=
      "$pCategories/*
                [$pMatchType = 'any']
                   [contains($vDecoratedCurrent,
                             concat('|', ., '|')
                              )
                   ][1]

       or
        not($pCategories/*[not(contains($vDecoratedCurrent,
                                        concat('|', ., '|')
                                        )
                               )
                          ][1]
            )
       "/>

       <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()[$vSelected]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<t>
 <select-criteria>
  <Categories>851|849</Categories>
  <MatchType>any</MatchType>
 </select-criteria>
 <pages>
  <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 1</Page>
  <Page CategoryIds="849|850|">Page 2</Page>
  <Page CategoryIds="848|850|">Page 3</Page>
  <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 4</Page>
  <Page CategoryIds="848|850|851">Page 5</Page>
  <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850">Page 6</Page>
 </pages>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 1</Page>
<Page CategoryIds="849|850|">Page 2</Page>
<Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 4</Page>
<Page CategoryIds="848|850|851">Page 5</Page>
<Page CategoryIds="848|849|850">Page 6</Page>
```

**When in the XML document we specify**:

```
  <MatchType>all</MatchType>
```

**we again get the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 1</Page>
<Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 4</Page>
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution! This is how to do it when there is posible to tokenize in node set by means of extension. Very good.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="vMatch">
        <Categories>851|849</Categories>
        <MatchType>any</MatchType>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:param name="pMatch" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='vMatch']"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Page" name="page">
        <xsl:param name="pCategories" select="$pMatch/Categories"/>
        <xsl:if test="$pCategories != ''">
            <xsl:variable name="vTest" select="contains(concat('|',
                                                                   @CategoryIds,
                                                                   '|'),
                                                            concat('|',
                                                                   substring-before(concat($pCategories,
                                                                                           '|'),
                                                                                    '|'),
                                                                   '|'))"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$vTest and ($pMatch/MatchType = 'any' or
                                            substring-after($pCategories,
                                                            '|')
                                            = '')">
                    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="($vTest and $pMatch/MatchType = 'all') or
                                $pMatch/MatchType = 'any' ">
                    <xsl:call-template name="page">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pCategories" select="substring-after($pCategories,'|')"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Whit this input:

```
<Pages>
    <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 1</Page>
    <Page CategoryIds="849|850|">Page 2</Page>
    <Page CategoryIds="848|850|">Page 3</Page>
    <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 4</Page>
    <Page CategoryIds="848|850|851">Page 5</Page>
    <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850">Page 6</Page>
</Pages>
```

Output:

```
<Pages>
    <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 1</Page>
    <Page CategoryIds="849|850|">Page 2</Page>
    <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 4</Page>
    <Page CategoryIds="848|850|851">Page 5</Page>
    <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850">Page 6</Page>
</Pages>
```

**Note:** Because I don't know where you get your `Categories` to test, I put those inline in the stylesheet. This has some optimization: after testing first category, success (call template `identity`) if category is found and match type is `any` or it's the last category to test, otherwise it makes a recursive call only if category is found and match type is `all` or category is not found and match type is `any`. So, it success with first match in `any` "mode" and fails with first fail in `all` "mode".

**Edit**: Just for fun, with Dimitre's input:

```
<t>
 <select-criteria>
  <Categories>851|849</Categories>
  <MatchType>all</MatchType>
 </select-criteria>
 <pages>
  <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 1</Page>
  <Page CategoryIds="849|850">Page 2</Page>
  <Page CategoryIds="848|850">Page 3</Page>
  <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850|851">Page 4</Page>
  <Page CategoryIds="848|850|851">Page 5</Page>
  <Page CategoryIds="848|849|850">Page 6</Page>
 </pages>
</t>
```

**One line XPath 2.0**:

```
/t/*/Page[(
           /t/*/MatchType = 'any' 
                   and 
           tokenize(/t/*/Categories,'\|') = tokenize(@CategoryIds,'\|')
          ) or (
           /t/*/MatchType = 'all' 
                   and 
           (every $x in tokenize(/t/*/Categories,'\|') 
            satisfies $x = tokenize(@CategoryIds,'\|'))
          )]
```

With XPath 2.1 `let` expression, it would be less verbose...

Comment: @Alejandro: Why is this complicated effort to produce the same results as the identity transform? How did you decide what the OP really wanted? Please, explain this mystery to me. :)

Comment: @Dimitre: First, because it was fun. Second, it's almost the indentity transform (missing Page 3), but of course you had already seen that. With less effort I had built a transformation with a `pState` param (initial false for "any", initial true for "all") changing with each recursion (or-logic with "any", and-logic with "all"). It was compact but iterating over all the tokens. It took me several minutes to came up with this optimizated version. Of course that my process does not make anything else that coping... But it was your answer what attracted me to respond! Ja!

Comment: @Alejandro: Sorry, I didn't see the small difference. Thanks to this now I finally understood what the OP wanted and produced a solution, which uses a single XPath expression after the tokenization of the categories in the match criteria.

Comment: @Dimitre: Of topic question: I was studing XPath 2.1 WD and it makes me think about why argument "sequence" for function invocation is treated special (say `$x(1 to 3)` it would be interpreted as `$x((1,2,3))` - one sequence argument - and not as `$x(1,2,3)` - a p/3 invocation -). But maybe this is because it would need nested sequence handling.

Comment: @Alejandro: `$f(someExpression)` clearly has just one argument. If a function invocation has more than one argument, each argument must be delimited from its neighbors by the comma character. Therefore, in `$x(1 to 3)` there is exactly one argument -- the sequence `1 to 3`. And yes, there isn't anything like a nested sequence datatype or a tuple datatype in XPath -- yet.

Comment: @Alejandro: Did you know that there is a SO chat? http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/